# How to enforce argument to be instance of constructor/class that is property of some object?

Tags: typescript

Here is my code.
Generally class keeps map of other classes and in a method I want to enforce that given key is accompanied by class instance which is instance of class kept in map at key. In comments you can see where ts shows errors.

```
abstract class AbstractSerializable {
  public abstract run(): void;
}

interface ISerializable {
  serialize: (cls: AbstractSerializable) => any;
  deserialize: (json: any) => AbstractSerializable;
}

type ClassMapItem = (new (...args: any[]) => AbstractSerializable) & ISerializable;

interface ClassMap {
  [key: string]: ClassMapItem;
}

abstract class AbstractClassManager<T extends ClassMap> {
  public readonly classMap: T;

  public serializeInstance<K extends keyof T>(
    key: K & string,
    instance: T[K], // <- I want to enforce "instance" to be instance of this.classMap[key]
  ): any {
    const Constructor = this.getClass(key);
    const json = Constructor.serialize(instance); // ERROR: Property 'run' is missing in type 'ClassMapItem'
    return json;
  }

  public getClass<K extends keyof T>(key: K & string) {
    return this.classMap[key];
  }
}

class SomeClass extends AbstractSerializable {
  public static serialize(c: SomeClass) {
    return {};
  }
  public static deserialize(json: any) {
    return new SomeClass();
  }

  public run() {
    return;
  }
}

const classMap: ClassMap = {
  someClass: SomeClass,
};

class ClassManager extends AbstractClassManager<typeof classMap> {

}

const manager = new ClassManager();
manager.serializeInstance('someClass', new SomeClass()); // ERROR: Type 'SomeClass' provides no match for the signature 'new (...args: any[]): AbstractSerializable'
```

Comment: I think you can boil this down to a much simpler question with about 7-10 lines of code, which might help you get answers. Basically you just need `ClassMap`, and a class with `<T extends ClassMap>` and a single method accepting `key` and `instance`, without all the other stuff (I think).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah .. this turns out to be a **very** simple answer, but it took me like 5 minutes to spot the actual issue :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the instance type from a constructor you can use the predefined [`InstanceType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#predefined-conditional-types) conditional type:

```
abstract class AbstractClassManager<T extends ClassMap> {
    public readonly classMap!: T;

    public serializeInstance<K extends keyof T>(
        key: K & string,
        instance: InstanceType<T[K]>, // The type of the instance T[K] returns
    ): any {
        const Constructor = this.getClass(key);
        const json = Constructor.serialize(instance);
        return json;
    }

    public getClass<K extends keyof T>(key: K) {
        return this.classMap[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.